# HttpPostedFileBase null when inside ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I searched the internet for possible problems that might be causing this and found nothing ...

When I put the `IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> FilesUploadedEvent` as action parameter alongside ViewModel everything seems to be working fine.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(EventViewModel model, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> FilesUploadedEvent)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ...
```

Problem is when I try to put it inside object in my ViewModel

```
@model ViewModels.Event.EventViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Event", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, null, new { @class = "validation-msg" })
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.BasicInfoSection)
    ...
    <input type="submit" value="Add" /> 
}
```

Controller after removing 2nd parameter:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(EventViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ...
```

ViewModel:

```
public class EventViewModel
{
    public BasicInfoSection BasicInfoSection { get; set; }
    ...
```

And we put the parameter inside ViewModels object:

```
public class BasicInfoSection : IValidatableObject
{
    public string Remarks { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> FilesUploadedEvent { get; set; }
    ...
```

and here is editor template for BasicInfoSection :

```
@model ViewModels.Event.Parts.BasicInfoSection 

<input id="FilesUploadedEvent" name="FilesUploadedEvent" type="file" data-role="upload" multiple="multiple" autocomplete="off">
@(Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Remarks, new { @class = "form-control", style = "height:200px;" }))
...
```

Also if the form wont validate on some other fields is it possible to return Files in the postBack? I read it is not because of security reasons. Is Ajax validation the only method than?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `name` attribute of the file input is not correct. Because `FilesUploadedEvent` is a property of `BasicInfoSection`, then in order to be bound on post back, the input would need to be

```
<input name="BasicInfoSection.FilesUploadedEvent" type="file" .. />
```

Note also how the `textarea`has the name attribute `name="BasicInfoSection.Remarks"`

Comment: This is great! I will try to remember this for future. As to my other part of the question.  Is it possible to return Files in the postBack? I read it is not because of security reasons. Is Ajax validation the only method than?

Comment: No you cant for security reasons - imagine if someone created a web site with a whole lot of file inputs named `C:password.doc` etc - they could steal your valuable files. You need to save the files first, then if you return the view you could display their file names and perhaps with an associated delete button so the user could change their mind